# Django reverse_lazy improperly configured

Tags: python, django

Under my once my user has signed up I would like to redirect them to the login page. However, reverse_lazy doesn't seem to be able to find my login path.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from . import forms

# Create your views here.
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
    #Redirect login page once they have successfully signed up
    succes_url = reverse_lazy('login')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(template_name='accounts/signup.html'), name='signup'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you specified an `app_name = …`, in that case you prefix the name of the view with the namespace:

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    # …
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:login')
```

You furthermore made a typo, it is [**`success_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url), not <s>`succes_url`</s>.

Comment: This does not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @djo: you also made a typo, it is `success_url` :)